# Why is the following code not taking required number of input?

Tags: java, recursion

```
void storedata(int i) {
    if(i > 0) {
        a[size-i] = in.nextInt();
        storedata(i--);
    }
}
```

The above code is not terminating after taking the required number of inputs. It runs forever. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the `in` variable, `System.in`?

Comment: Upvoted you as your a new contributor. But the code is not complete, cant understand it, post more information, like full program and description of what your expecting it to do

Comment: Did you debug the`i` value? It can't go in negative for sure. Check the caller of the function. Debug and let us know.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @tgkprog: please do not upvote merely because someone is new. This can prompt a flurry of downvotes to cancel out the unmerited score, which in turn may contribute to an automated question ban.

Answer (score 2):

You will always call `storeData` recursively with the same value, because you used

```
storedata(i--);
```

Try using

```
storedata(--i);
```

instead. That will decrement `i` first.

Comment: The proper way would be to use `i - 1`. i doesn't need to be modified.

Comment: true. I just wanted to emphasise the difference between i-- and --i.